# Passing 'program arguments' to cf run-task in CloudFoundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, sap-cloud-foundry

I have deployed a Spring-boot app for a task/job in PCF. I can also able to tigger the 'main' method of the springboot app using below command .

```sh
cf run-task APP-NAME "$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java 
org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"
```

But I would like to pass 'programme arguments' as we pass in IntelliJ IDE , so that I can get that value in args of main method.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
```

expecting a command like ,

```sh
cf run-task APP-NAME "$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java 
org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --arg0=value0 --arg1=value1"
```

Please let me know if you came across this use-cases.Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Does that not work? `cf run-task` takes the full and exact command that you'd like it to run. That includes the command and all it's arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define parameters for your program with:

`cf set-env APP-NAME arg0 value0 arg1 value1`

Best practice ask to restage your app after that:

`cf restage APP-NAME`

Now you can run your program as usual:

`cf run-task APP-NAME "$PWD/.java-buildpack/oracle_jre/bin/java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"`